# MS CRM 2011 Duplicate Call deletion

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

We have many users where they have multiple open calls schedule for the same contact. They should only ever have one open call.

I'd like to be able to delete (or cancel) all but own of the open scheduled calls?

Answer (score 0):

I'd  write a console app that uses the SDK to retrieve all open calls, groups them by contact and then delete (or cancel) all but one of each call in the group.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a plugin on the create of call record to prevent the creation of multiple open call records related to that specific contact.